# How to dynamically create MapQuickItem in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to dynamically create MapQuickItem, but I can't. My code:

```
anotherItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtLocation 5.15; MapQuickItem {sourceItem: Image { id: xyz; source: "qrc:/abc.png"}}', map)
```

I get error:

```
Image is not a type
```

Comment: try add `import QtQuick 2.15`: `anotherItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; import QtLocation 5.15; MapQuickItem {sourceItem: Image { id: xyz; source: "qrc:/abc.png"}}', map)
`

Comment: @eyllanesc Gracias! Danke! Thank you! Perfect! :)